# StackOverflow showing else{} at the top

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

It seems the mobile site for Stackoverflow is showing an empty `else{}` in plain text when navigating (logged in and logged out). Screenshot to follow once uploaded.

[image]

Thanks to for the edit, beating me to the punch. But it's showing both navigation bars, when both are expanded the else{} is hidden away

[image]

Comment: If the closing brace was a line lower, then it would literally be saying Stack Overflow catches all the exceptions :D

Comment: Seems to have spanned to meta site, not sure if others are experiencing the same problem. IE serverfault, Superuser etc. **Edit** Has spanned across Serverfault/Superuser

Comment: what `else` would you expect it to show?

Comment: +1 for cropping/resizing imaeg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A drunk developer pushed some code - he's being appropriately beaten and a fix is rolling out now.

Comment: I mean I know it's Kevin's birthday, but it seems a little early to start celebrating.

Comment: [Aren't all your answers guesses?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver)

Comment: Beaten, right? Not poked with a sharp stick, right? You have me concerned.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I think Rebecca took all the sharp sticks with her when she left. :)